# Java Spring Boot accessing MariaDB's View?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, mariadb

I'm trying to connect my code with a view in my database.

For example : 
        `SELECT * FROM Employee_Tardiness;` 
The actual view is longer and more complicate.

How does JPA implement the view to call api from it or is there any other ways to connect to the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JPA implementation (most likely Hibernate) does not care if you are connecting an entity to a table or a view. 
Therefore for reading data you have to do nothing special. 
Just map an entity to the view as you would to a normal table.

For writing things might get a little or really tricky. 
The important question is: "[Is the view updatable?](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/inserting-and-updating-with-views/)"
This basically means is it possible for your RDBMS to translate an insert/update statement to your view into a insert/update statement to your tables.

If that is not the case in theory one could use an `INSTEAD OF` trigger on the view but this does not seem to be supported by MariaDb.

*Note: Spring Boot has nothing to do with the mapping of entities. It is all done by your JPA implementation. Even Spring Data JPA just makes using JPA a little more comfortable. The mapping is still done by JPA.*

Comment: Thanks a lot ! This is very helpful !!!
I'm think in the case that if I need any add-on to the view, I should just modify the code or create one more view.